# How to program an EXE to become a service on Windows?

Tags: visual-c++, rpc

I have developed a simple RPC server in executable format using Visual C++. Now I would like it to run as a service at Windows boot up. How to program this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Windows you are using, you can use Sc to do it as shown at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192.

To fully integrate, there are many guides: one is at http://www.muukka.net/programming/service/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to create a windows service template from Visual Studio:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40xe80wx(v=vs.80).aspx

... then cut-and-paste.

Comment: is this template is already RPC look alike? Means, does it works like a RPC too?

Comment: It's a generic windows service template. You already have the code for your RPC server, it should be simple enough to plug it in the generated source files.